# click function on kwindow object instance (kendo-ui)

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

```
self.kwindow = initWindow();
```

The below does not work; **how can I add a click function on my above `kwindow` object instance?**

```
  self.kwindow.on('click',function(){ <---- this errors, not a function
     //....
  });
```

Comment: you want click event to be called on every part of window or?

Comment: yes, that would work

Comment: What `initWindow();` does and what it returns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I would add click event on window wrapper when the window opens for the first time.

```
var isOnClickEventRegistered = false;

$("#window").kendoWindow({
  .
  .
  .
  open: {
    if(!isOnClickEventRegistered) {
      $("#window").getKendoWindow().wrapper.on('click', function() {
        console.log("Click");
      });
      isOnClickEventRegistered = true;  
    }
  }
});
```

Example: [Window click event](https://dojo.telerik.com/iWADUFOs)